# Why can't I get time in a `do` block?

Tags: haskell, time, io, websocket

I have this function which is responsible for communication in a web chat. Everything works fine without `t <- getClockTime` (here is code with it):

```
talk :: WS.Protocol p => MVar State -> Client -> WS.WebSockets p ()
talk state client@(user, sink) = flip WS.catchWsError catchDisconnect $ 
  forever $ do
    t <- getClockTime
    msg <- WS.receiveData
    case () of
      () | T.unpack(msg) == "#list" -> liftIO $ readMVar state >>= listClients client
        | T.unpack(msg) == "#time" -> liftIO (sendTime client)
        | "#name" `T.isPrefixOf` msg -> liftIO (command msg client)
        | otherwise -> liftIO $ readMVar state >>= broadcast
          (user `mappend` msg)
  where
    catchDisconnect e = case fromException e of
        Just WS.ConnectionClosed -> liftIO $ modifyMVar_ state $ \s -> do
            let new_state = removeClient client s
            return new_state
        _ -> return ()
```

With `t <- getClockTime` I get error:

```
Couldn't match type `WS.WebSockets p0' with `IO'
Expected type: IO Text
  Actual type: WS.WebSockets p0 Text
In a stmt of a 'do' block: msg <- WS.receiveData
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `do { t <- getClockTime;
        msg <- WS.receiveData;
        case () of {
          ()
            | T.unpack (msg) == "#list"
            -> liftIO $ readMVar state >>= listClients client
            | T.unpack (msg) == "#time" -> liftIO (sendTime client)
            | "#name" `T.isPrefixOf` msg -> liftIO (command msg client)
            | otherwise
            -> liftIO $ readMVar state >>= broadcast (user `mappend` msg) } }'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `forever
   $ do { t <- getClockTime;
          msg <- WS.receiveData;
          case () of {
            ()
              | T.unpack (msg) == "#list"
              -> liftIO $ readMVar state >>= listClients client
              | T.unpack (msg) == "#time" -> liftIO (sendTime client)
              | "#name" `T.isPrefixOf` msg -> liftIO (command msg client)
              | otherwise
              -> liftIO $ readMVar state >>= broadcast (user `mappend` msg) } }'
```

How can I get this time and concatenate it with msg?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your monad isn't `IO`. I have no idea what `WS.WebSockets` is, but if it's [this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.7.1.1/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html), it's an instance of `MonadIO`, so you can use [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.7.1.1/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html)`getClockTime`. I recommend reading more about monad transformers for this sort of code, because lifting is going to come up a lot.